# Interpreting color function and adjusting pixels values

Tags: c++, image, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

Here is the definition which i read from the net source

1st is

> `Midtone: Situated between the darkest tone (Black), and the brightest tone (White). For a 24 bit colour image, this occurs when Red = Green = Blue = 128.`

and the other is

```
Tones created by dots between 30% and 70% of coverage
```

and

> `Midtone also refers to the range of colors that aren't mixed with black (the shadows) or white (the highlights).`

What i got from these definition is that the pixels whose values are 0 or 255 we should adjust them to 128 . Am i taking the definition right ? I don't want to use the way of Histogram Equalization as according to my knowledge its also use for brightness of image

I want to perform the function like below , like i want to perform this function in `OpenCV C++` but i don't know the idea of how to deal with Midtones and CYMK values as it has both RGB and CMYK at the same time

[image]

For example
Sample image

[image]

After applying the above values

[image]

I want to do the same in OpenCV

My concern is only with the result if we can perform this with only RGB

**EDIT**

Answer from Andrey is good but still waiting for the best answer as this answer is difficult for other images to adjust other values of color balance

Comment: Where can I see the example of functionality you want in dynamics? Please name any prototypes.

Comment: You're asking us to reverse engineer Photoshop - that's a big job. I don't think the specifics of this control are published anywhere.

Comment: @MarkRansom I just want to know how i can do it the logic is all my need , its just the game of colors but its out of my logic :)

Comment: if i can perform the same function using just RGB or any opencv function then i don't need this control

Comment: If you can describe the effect you're looking for in terms other than Photoshop controls, maybe someone can help.

Comment: I don't have , actually i want to work on it , to use this control in opencv

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think in this case, Shadows, Midtones and Highlights defines the range of trackbars values.

- Shadows - precise adjusting (small range);
- Midtones - medium adjusting (medium range);
- Highlights - heavy adjusting (wide range).

It allows fast and precise color correction.

The code snippet:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <functional>
#include <algorithm>
#include <numeric>
#include <cstddef>
#include "opencv2/opencv.hpp"
using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

int val_Cyan_Red=0;
int val_Magenta_Green=0;
int val_Yellow_Blue=0;
Mat result;
Mat Img;

void on_trackbar( int, void* )
{
float SH=0.1; // The scale of trackbar ( depends on ajusting mode Shadows/Midtones/Highlights )

float cr_val=(float)val_Cyan_Red/255.0;
float mg_val=(float)val_Magenta_Green/255.0;
float yb_val=(float)val_Yellow_Blue/255.0;
// Cyan_Red
float R1=0;
float G1=1;
float B1=1;

float R2=1;
float G2=0;
float B2=0;

float DR=(1-cr_val)*R1+(cr_val)*R2-0.5;
float DG=(1-cr_val)*G1+(cr_val)*G2-0.5;
float DB=(1-cr_val)*B1+(cr_val)*B2-0.5;

result=Img+(Scalar(DB,DG,DR)*SH);

// Magenta_Green
 R1=1;
 G1=0;
 B1=1;

 R2=0;
 G2=1;
 B2=0;

 DR=(1-mg_val)*R1+(mg_val)*R2-0.5;
 DG=(1-mg_val)*G1+(mg_val)*G2-0.5;
 DB=(1-mg_val)*B1+(mg_val)*B2-0.5;

result+=(Scalar(DB,DG,DR)*SH);

// Yellow_Blue

 R1=1;
 G1=1;
 B1=0;

 R2=0;
 G2=0;
 B2=1;

 DR=(1-yb_val)*R1+(yb_val)*R2-0.5;
 DG=(1-yb_val)*G1+(yb_val)*G2-0.5;
 DB=(1-yb_val)*B1+(yb_val)*B2-0.5;

result+=(Scalar(DB,DG,DR)*SH);

imshow("Result",result);
waitKey(10);
}

// ---------------------------------
// 
// ---------------------------------
int main( int argc, char** argv )
{
    namedWindow("Image",cv::WINDOW_NORMAL);
    namedWindow("Result");

    Img=imread("D:\\ImagesForTest\\cat2.jpg",1);
    Img.convertTo(Img,CV_32FC1,1.0/255.0);  

   createTrackbar("CyanRed", "Image", &val_Cyan_Red, 255, on_trackbar);
   createTrackbar("MagentaGreen", "Image", &val_Magenta_Green, 255, on_trackbar);
   createTrackbar("YellowBlue", "Image", &val_Yellow_Blue, 255, on_trackbar);

    imshow("Image",Img);
    waitKey(0);
}
```

Yhe result for approximately the values above (zero offset is 128):
[image]

Comment: What about computing the Cyan and Green and blue , and i only have to use Midtone then why i need to multiply delta with others like shadow and highlight

Comment: You can convert RGB to CMYK as applying formulas from here: http://rapidtables.com/convert/color/rgb-to-cmyk.htm  and back http://rapidtables.com/convert/color/cmyk-to-rgb.htm  Imagine, that you need precisely set some value, then you should have very long scale (it can simply not fit in your display). To solve this problem you can set it in three steps : 1) set roughly 2) set more precise 2) justify final value. It will be fast and precise.

Comment: in above function , control perform first effect only on cyan and magentta from CMYK and then blue from BGR , so first i convert my image to CMYK add cyan and magenta and then change to BGR and then subtract blue ?

Comment: Cyan = (1,0,0,0) ; Red = (0,1,1,0)    Magenta(0,1,0,0) ; Green (1,0,1,0)   Yellow(0,0,1,0) ; Blue (1,1,0,0). As you see every scrollbar changes 3 values. You need to convert rgb to cmyk then adjust values (I guess by deltas got from multiplying channels from each scrollbar). Then convert it back to rgb.

Comment: I've corrected my answer. For example left side is Cyan (1,0,0,0) middle (0.5,0.5,0.5,0) right is Red(0,1,1,0). That's why you need precisely set these values. Set for test DS=0.01; DM=0.1; DH=1.0;

Comment: nops sorry its not giving me the required result , if the result is near to it , it is acceptable but its quite different result

Comment: thanks a million , why this line show me error `result+=(Scalar(DB,DG,DR)*SH);`

Comment: That error? It may be related on OpenCV version or namespace. You can replace it with result=result+(Scalar(DB,DG,DR)*SH);

Comment: yes it show me error , don't know why , i think its because of multiplication of matrix and double , result=result+(Scalar(DB,DG,DR)*SH); show the error on `+` too

Comment: What compiler writes to console? Or it is runtime error?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51734/discussion-between-andrey-smorodov-and-ahmad)

Comment: @AndreySmorodov could you explain how you derived the formulas like `DR=(1-yb_val)*R1+(yb_val)*R2-0.5;` and how SH determines the range of whether it's Highlights, Shadows, etc. I'm not very good at math...

Comment: It is just a crossfade ) , A*x+B*(1-x)=Val . If x=0 then Val will be A if x=1 then V will be equals to B. So if A and B are color component vectors, changing x from 0 to 1 will smoothly change result from A to B.

Answer (score 3):

Mid-Tone regions are the intermediate shaded areas in any image, at almost halfway between brightest and the darkest area of an image, it is not necessary that they have to be around 128. In case of overexposed image the mid-tones region will be at much higher value compared to a dark or under-exposed image.
 However if you perform histrogram equalization, then it will be set to a value close to 128[for 8-bit image].

Regarding how to obtain the mid-tonal region, I think you can simply get this information from histrogram.

1. convert your image to gray scale.
2. Get the histrogram.
3. Do Histrogram equalization.
4. Now the centeral intersity values(e.g between 255/3 to 2*255/3) are
   the mid-tones.

Answer (score 2):

Use OpenCV's split function to split the image into red, green, and blue channels.

Now, from the looks of the second image, it appears that the blues and greens are more prominent and the reds are being suppressed.  So, divide the red channel by, say, 1.5.

Then use the OpenCV's merge function to recombine the channels.  Now, you have the same image but the reds are weaker than the blues and greens, and this should result in the desired image.