# Can somebody explain the mathematics of this Color Balance formula?

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing

I have found a good example of a Color Balance implementation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23213925/interpreting-color-function-and-adjusting-pixels-values) and was wondering if someone could explain the derivation of these formula's:

```
float DR=(1-cr_val)*R1+(cr_val)*R2-0.5;
float DG=(1-cr_val)*G1+(cr_val)*G2-0.5;
float DB=(1-cr_val)*B1+(cr_val)*B2-0.5;
```

The full code is here:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <functional>
#include <algorithm>
#include <numeric>
#include <cstddef>
#include "opencv2/opencv.hpp"
using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

int val_Cyan_Red=0;
int val_Magenta_Green=0;
int val_Yellow_Blue=0;
Mat result;
Mat Img;

void on_trackbar( int, void* )
{
float SH=0.1; // The scale of trackbar ( depends on ajusting mode Shadows/Midtones/Highlights )

float cr_val=(float)val_Cyan_Red/255.0;
float mg_val=(float)val_Magenta_Green/255.0;
float yb_val=(float)val_Yellow_Blue/255.0;
// Cyan_Red
float R1=0;
float G1=1;
float B1=1;

float R2=1;
float G2=0;
float B2=0;

float DR=(1-cr_val)*R1+(cr_val)*R2-0.5;
float DG=(1-cr_val)*G1+(cr_val)*G2-0.5;
float DB=(1-cr_val)*B1+(cr_val)*B2-0.5;

result=Img+(Scalar(DB,DG,DR)*SH);

// Magenta_Green
 R1=1;
 G1=0;
 B1=1;

 R2=0;
 G2=1;
 B2=0;

 DR=(1-mg_val)*R1+(mg_val)*R2-0.5;
 DG=(1-mg_val)*G1+(mg_val)*G2-0.5;
 DB=(1-mg_val)*B1+(mg_val)*B2-0.5;

result+=(Scalar(DB,DG,DR)*SH);

// Yellow_Blue

 R1=1;
 G1=1;
 B1=0;

 R2=0;
 G2=0;
 B2=1;

 DR=(1-yb_val)*R1+(yb_val)*R2-0.5;
 DG=(1-yb_val)*G1+(yb_val)*G2-0.5;
 DB=(1-yb_val)*B1+(yb_val)*B2-0.5;

result+=(Scalar(DB,DG,DR)*SH);

imshow("Result",result);
waitKey(10);
}

// ---------------------------------
// 
// ---------------------------------
int main( int argc, char** argv )
{
    namedWindow("Image",cv::WINDOW_NORMAL);
    namedWindow("Result");

    Img=imread("D:\\ImagesForTest\\cat2.jpg",1);
    Img.convertTo(Img,CV_32FC1,1.0/255.0);  

   createTrackbar("CyanRed", "Image", &val_Cyan_Red, 255, on_trackbar);
   createTrackbar("MagentaGreen", "Image", &val_Magenta_Green, 255, on_trackbar);
   createTrackbar("YellowBlue", "Image", &val_Yellow_Blue, 255, on_trackbar);

    imshow("Image",Img);
    waitKey(0);
}
```

[image]

Additionally, the OP talks about how changing the scale of the trackbar adjusts the shadows, mid-tones, and highlights. What values would I change it to in order to make changes in those ranges?

Comment: I would expect that the function for each color should _not_ be linaer as those you use, but ... interesting.

Comment: @TedLyngmo any idea how to explain it?

Comment: No, I just lived next door to a person working in this field and colors have never seemed easy after that.

Comment: A lot of color math is performed in a linear space, and then later transformed into other spaces with different gamuts. If you look at these calculations, you do see how they are just interpolating between the two ends: _e.g._ Cyan (0,1,1) -> Red (1,0,0). They are weighted around the center point 0.5, which you can see by the subtraction that takes place. I would guess that modifying the scale of the track bar involves adjusting where its midpoint falls and also what width of values it covers. Right now it's 0-1, but you may want centers at 0.25 (shadow), 0.5 (mid) and 0.75 (high). Experiment.

Comment: Distinct_Cabinet : @paddy is not my former neighbour, but speaks the color language well enough :-)

Comment: @Distinct_Cabinet I'm not a color expert in any way. I suggested that you experiment, because I don't know enough about this topic off-hand to knock out an answer, nor do I have time to experiment for you. I provided some ideas. Just try things. Consider that a full-range color balance operates over 0-1 with a center of 0.5. Now, a partial balance might operate over a range 0-0.5 with a center of 0.25. I expect you could run all these sub-ranges and combine. You might need to clamp some values, and you might need to scale some ranges. You might need to experiment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is just a linear interpolation between C1(R1, G1, B1) and C2(R2, G2, B2).

If you imagine C1 and C2 as points in 3D space, `c_val` lets you choose a point on the line that goes from C1 to C2.

- 0 is on C1
- 1 is on C2
- anything in (0,1) is on the line segment between (C1, C2)
- anything below 0 or above 1 is extrapolated.

Subtracting 0.5 just changes the space from [0,1] to [-0.5, 0.5]

Comment: What does `(1-cr_val)*R1` mean?

Comment: The idea is that as cr_val slowly moves from 0 to 1, the "portion" of contribution from R1 goes from 100% to 0%